# Set value for angular6 select option using reactive FormGroup or FormControlName

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6

I tried to set the value for angular6 select(Drop down) via setValue() with help of reactiveform method but only input value are setting which i assigned but not assign for drop down i need help on this.

```
<div [formGroup]="empOrInstuteFormData">
<mat-form-field fxFlex="100%" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Select Client</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="empclientname">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let empclient of empclients" [value]="empclient.id">{{empclient.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
</div>

 editCellData(tabelinfo) {
    this.empOrInstuteFormData.setValue({
      type: '',
      empnamesearch: '',
      employername: tabelinfo.employername,
      institutenamesearch: '',
      empclientname: tabelinfo.clientname,
      empaddress: tabelinfo.address,
      instituteName: '',
      institutecategory: '',
      instituteclient: '',
      institutedate: '',
      instituteaddorlocation: '',
      institutesource: '',
      instituteresearchorremark: '',
      instituecomments: ''
    })
  }
```

While click table edit icon this editcellData() method will call and display corresponding input fields. But dropdown down not select the values.

Comment: Here empclientname is dropdown field

Comment: i tried by following way but now working some one tell me where i wrong                         this.empOrInstuteFormData.patchValue({
      employername: tabelinfo.employername,
      empclientname: tabelinfo.clientname,
      empaddress: tabelinfo.address,
    })